# cross validation + decision trees in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, cross-validation

Attempting to create a decision tree with cross validation using sklearn and panads.

My question is in the code below, the cross validation splits the data, which i then use for both training and testing.  I will be attempting to find the best depth of the tree by recreating it n times with different max depths set.  In using cross validation should i instead be using k folds CV and if so how would I use that within the code I have?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import cross_validation

features = ["fLength", "fWidth", "fSize", "fConc", "fConc1", "fAsym", "fM3Long", "fM3Trans", "fAlpha", "fDist", "class"]

df = pd.read_csv('magic04.data',header=None,names=features)

df['class'] = df['class'].map({'g':0,'h':1})

x = df[features[:-1]]
y = df['class']

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)

depth = []
for i in range(3,20):
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=i)
    clf = clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
    depth.append((i,clf.score(x_test,y_test)))
print depth
```

here is a link to the data that i am using in case that helps anyone.  https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/MAGIC+Gamma+Telescope

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In your code you are creating a static training-test split. If you want to select the best depth by cross-validation you can use `sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score` inside the for loop.

You can read [sklearn's documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics) for more information.

Here is an update of your code with CV:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from pprint import pprint

features = ["fLength", "fWidth", "fSize", "fConc", "fConc1", "fAsym", "fM3Long", "fM3Trans", "fAlpha", "fDist", "class"]

df = pd.read_csv('magic04.data',header=None,names=features)
df['class'] = df['class'].map({'g':0,'h':1})

x = df[features[:-1]]
y = df['class']

# x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)
depth = []
for i in range(3,20):
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=i)
    # Perform 7-fold cross validation 
    scores = cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=x, y=y, cv=7, n_jobs=4)
    depth.append((i,scores.mean()))
print(depth)
```

Alternatively, you can use `sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV` and not write the for loop yourself, especially if you want to optimize for more than one hyper-parameter.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

features = ["fLength", "fWidth", "fSize", "fConc", "fConc1", "fAsym", "fM3Long", "fM3Trans", "fAlpha", "fDist", "class"]

df = pd.read_csv('magic04.data',header=None,names=features)
df['class'] = df['class'].map({'g':0,'h':1})

x = df[features[:-1]]
y = df['class']


parameters = {'max_depth':range(3,20)}
clf = GridSearchCV(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(), parameters, n_jobs=4)
clf.fit(X=x, y=y)
tree_model = clf.best_estimator_
print (clf.best_score_, clf.best_params_)
```

**Edit:** changed how GridSearchCV is imported to accommodate learn2day's comment.

Comment: +1 for answering the question asked and also suggesting grid search, which is definitely the better practice for this type of problem

Comment: `grid_search` is deprecated since 0.18, and removed since 0.20. You should now use `GridSearchCV` from `sklearn.model_selection`

Comment: @Dimosthenis How will the model be validated on a _test_ dataset since all the data is used in training the model ?

Comment: Or shall we keep a part of dataset as a _test_ dataset and should not use that even for cross validation

Comment: @Rookie_123 If you choose to use cross validation to optimize the model's hyper parameters then it's better to do a train/test split first, train and do cross validation on the training set, and test at the end on the first test set you created. `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` is handy for the train test split

Comment: Got it, Thanks :)

Comment: The GridSearch will optimize the parameters (variable order and thresholds) using the training data, and the hyperparameters using the validation data.
What about the pruning? Will they be optimized with the same validation data, or with the training data (but internally further split into a new training-validation)?